# Why is my spl_autoload_register registered function not being called?

Tags: php, classloader, autoload

Here's my code:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className){
    die("Test");
    //...some autoload codes
});
```

I wonder why it's not calling the die() function inside. `spl_autoload_register` is at the top of my code. No any other code, simple starting classes, just plain this.

Comment: The `spl_autoload_register()` loads classes on the fly, so it will not run anything until you instantiate a class.

Comment: @Rasclatt surely that could be an answer

Comment: @TobyAllen I didn't think it warranted an actual answer, it's pretty straight forward and on the edge of a low-quality post, but I have answered with an expanded example to illustrate a working test. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spl_autoload_register()` loads classes on the fly, so it will not run anything until you instantiate a class. Try:

```
<?php

function myFunc($class)
    {
        die("Tried it!");
    }

spl_autoload_register("myFunc");

$test = new MyClass();

?>
```

Should echo `Tried it!`